# Start Django project by one clik using BAT file

Tags: django, batch-file, cmd

I want the user press one icon (link to BAT file) on the DESKTOP and it starts two processes.

first - start django server

second - crome

file.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
start cmd.exe "D: && cd D:\D1\ && python manage.py runserver"
start C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"
```

where is my mistake? BAT file just start cmd.exe and go to directory D:\D1 and nothing more.
The sintax of the second line is correct.

Where is the error?

Comment: Did you try to add `""` to the start command? This is the parameter that usually indicates the title of the window.

Comment: Yes I try but no changes. CMD is starting, go to D:\D1\ folder and the last comand "python manage.py runserver" is not processing

Comment: `start "" cmd.exe "cd /D D:\D1\ && python manage.py runserver"`

Comment: If using `Start` then better advice would be to use its **`/D`** option to set the working/current directory…`Start "" /D "D:\D1" "<executable>" <options>`. _@Mircea, I also showed you how to structure the chrome line in a response to you the other day, in which you abused me, you appear to have ignored that advice_.

Comment: LotPings - it does not work. Compo - I did not abuse You, I wrote the concrete code and I need a concrete answer. At last I notice the correct code: start cmd.exe /C "python manage.py runserver & cd D:\D1\ & D:"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
start cmd.exe /C "python manage.py runserver && cd D:\D1\ && D:"
start C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"
```